# URL encoding to enocode spaces with plus

Tags: javascript, php, encodeuricomponent

I have an application that needs to sign form data before it is sent to server. In the signing method, I have to escape all form input values with javascript, sign them and then send the signed data to server for cross matching. The remote server is escaping form data in a way that it enocodes all spaces with plus.

So if my form data is:

```
this is test :)
```

The encoded output should be

```
this+is+test+%3A)
```

But I tested javascripts encodeURIComponent, encodeURI and escape. All of them gives me the following output:

```
this%20is%20test%20%3A)
```

Any ideas which function is right for this?

Comment: did you use urldecode with php ? http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php

Comment: Are you sure that your server can't handle %20 if it handles %3A for the colon?

Comment: @CsakZoli PHP part is handled by remote api server. All I have to do is using javascript.

Answer (score 3):

It is quite straightforward to do the replacement yourself:

```
var encoded = escape(s).replace(/%20/g, "+");
alert(encoded); // outputs "this+is+test+%3A)"
```